# Wald test for terms in a regression model in R

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to use Wald test to calculate for a term in an ordinal regression model, but I obtain an error result whenever I try to run it in R.

My ordinal regression model:

```
model1 <- polr(as.factor(df1$DLQI_Total_Score_Cat) ~ df1$PredictedClassMembership + df1$age + df1$gender + df1$SCORAD, data = df1, Hess = TRUE, method = "logistic")
```

My attempt at the Wald test:

```
regTermTest(model1, "PredictedClassMembership", method="Wald")
```

When I try to run it, it says: "Error in solve.default(V) : 'a' is 0-diml"

My goal is to calculate the Wald test and associated P value for each term in the ordinal regression model (PredictedClassMembership, age, gender, and SCORAD).  I was planning on looking at them one at a time.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this code?

Thanks so much for your help!